# Are there any rules for player-character ogres in Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay Second Edition?

Tags: wfrp-2e

The question is in the title. I am aware that players can create ogre characters in the third edition, but are there any rules for similar characters in second edition? If so, in which book, magazine, or website do they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Law (Lawhammer on blogger, @Lawhammer on twitter, and Andrew Law on G+) wrote [*Imperial Ogres*](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1VAfqp6rZDgS2NqOTBiaWZMOTA/edit?usp=sharing) for Black Industries. The article was lost in the closing of BI, but I've linked it here (at whatever risk that puts me, but it was publicly shared previously and I'm not claiming any rights).

From the opening of the supplement

> This character supplement for Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay (WFRP) provides you with all of the rules required to include Ogre Player Characters (PCs) in a game centred in the Empire.
>
> GMs thinking of adding Ogre PCs to their game should seriously consider the impact of such a move. Not only are Ogres particularly strong in combat, which can imbalance certain scenarios, they are also very weak in social situations, which many WFRP adventures focus upon. Ogres are not as accepted by the general folk of the Old World as Elves and Dwarves (primarily due to their belligerent natures), which can have massive repercussions on the enjoyment of playing an Ogre, who may have to miss, or will simply ruin, subtler adventures.

I think this answers your question. See you on G+.

Comment: [There's an unpublished update...](https://twitter.com/LAWHAMMERblog/status/385765191729688576)